# CSS and Images in HTML E-Mail

Tags: c#, html, css, email

I'd like to send HTML E-Mails from my ASP.NET Core application.
For that I'm using a library called FluentEmail. With that you can also user Razor as template engine for your Mail templates.

My problem is that the CSS, which is inside a style tag inside my templates head tag, has no effect on the mail when viewing in Gmail or Outlook for example.

Also images which lie on a ftp server don't display properly. In Outlook I get the error message:

> The linked image cannot be displayed. The file may have been moved,
> renamed, or deleted. Verify that the link points to the correct file
> and location.

The weird thing is that when I reply to that E-Mail the image gets displayed fine in my answer.

My CSHTML looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        p {
            padding: 0 0 1rem 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 2.37rem;
            font-weight: bold;
            line-height: 1.1;
            padding-bottom: 2rem;
            margin: 0;
        }

        h2 {
            font-size: 1.78rem;
            font-weight: bold;
            line-height: 1.1;
            padding-bottom: 1rem;
            margin: 0;
        }

        h3 {
            font-size: 1.33rem;
            font-weight: bold;
            line-height: 1.1;
            padding-bottom: 1rem;
            margin: 0;
        }

        h4 {
            font-size: 1rem;
            font-weight: bold;
            line-height: 1.4;
            padding-bottom: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }


    html,
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 2rem;
        padding: 2rem;
    }

    .header {
        width: 20%;
    }

    .content {
        padding: 2rem 5rem 2rem 5rem;
    }
        </style>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>???</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        CONTENT HERE
      <img src="https://PATH TO FILE.svg">
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My C# code looks like this:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

await Email.From("???", "???")
  .To(recipients)
  .Subject(mail.Subject)
  .UsingTemplateFromEmbedded(mail.TemplateFile, mail.TemplateModel, assembly)
  .SendAsync();
```

Do I have to pay attention to something special when using images and css in HTML Mails?

Comment: The image issue is probably due to SVG support within email clients being low see https://www.caniemail.com/features/image-svg/ as for the style tag again this is down to email clients support. Email clients are very fussy when it comes to how the markup is structured. Emails are usually a table structure with the styles inline. There are many tutorials on this for example https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/build-an-html-email-template-from-scratch--webdesign-12770

Comment: Ok yes, the SVG was an issue. In terms of the styling issue different email clients seem to behave very differently. Sometimes a style tag is okay but some css properties are ignored and sometimes only inline styles work.

Comment: I am afraid all email clients are different so they all support different levels of CSS and even HTML. If you need to identify if the CSS is valid in the email client you support look for the CSS property here https://www.caniemail.com/. The safest email templates use table markup and inline styles.

Comment: Wow, that's a very useful site.
Since I'm using SendGrid for sending mails I will create my templates with their template builder. Creating those templates with inline styles and tables manually is just too much effort.
It's a shame that such an old but still frequently used and relevant technology like emails lacks proper support for such basic features.